# Proving a lemma concerning the cardinality of two sets

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I'm currently doing my homework, and in order to facilitate all of the exercises, I decided to prove the following lemma:

Assume that $E$ and $F$ are two finite sets and $f$ is a function from $E$ to $F$. Then:

$f$ injective $\implies |E|\le|F|$

$f$ surjective $\implies |E|\ge|F|$

My prove goes as follows:

Let $|E|=n$ and $E=\{e_1,...,e_n\}$ and define $G=\{f(e_1),...,f(e_n)\}$. If $f$ is injective, then $f(e_1),...,f(e_n)$ are all different, so $|G|=n$. But $G$ is a subset of $F$, thus $|E|=n=|G|\le|F|$.

If $f$ is surjective, then $G=F$. But $G$ contains at most $n$ different elements, thus $|E|=n\ge|G|=|F|$.

Is this prove precise enough? I have a few doubts concerning it, because the proofs of my colleagues are all quite tedious.

Answer (score 1):

Looks good, but to be precise, it depends on how you (or your teacher) defined "finite set". Sorry, let me clarify: the common definition of a finite set is that of one that can be put into a one-to-one (bijective) correspondence with an initial segment $\{1,\dotsc,n\}$ of the natural numbers $\mathbb N$ which is assumed to exist.  In practical terms, a set $A$ is finite if you can find an $n\in\mathbb N$ such that you can "index" *all* the elements of $A$, as $a_i$, for $1\leq i\leq n$, so that $$a_i=a_j\Leftrightarrow i=j.$$  On the other hand *by**definition* of $\mathbb N$, two integers $m$ and $n$ satisfy at least one of $m\leq n$ or $n\leq m$ if and only if there is an injective map from $\{1,\dotsc,m\}$ into $\{1,\dotsc,n\}$ or viceversa.

Assuming you now know that the composition of injective maps is injective and that of surjective maps is surjective, then your result is fully rigorous.

Comment: What do you mean?